# Unable to create procedure for inserting data in two tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables `tbl_pattern` and `tbl_pattern_features`

I would like to insert the data into tbl_pattern_features against the last_insert_id of tbl_pattern.
Here is the query:

```
BEGIN

DROP INDEX fld_pattern_name ON tbl_pattern;
CREATE INDEX fld_pattern_name ON tbl_pattern (fld_pattern_name);

DECLARE @NewID INT(10)

IF pAction = "INSERT" THEN
INSERT INTO tbl_pattern(fld_pattern_name, fld_pattern_category, fld_pattern_utqg, pattern_image, fld_pattern_title, fld_pattern_description)
    VALUES (ppattern_name, ppattern_category, ppattern_utqg, ppattern_image, ppattern_title, ppattern_descrip);

SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO tbl_pattern_features(fld_pattern_id, fld_feature_name, fld_feature_description, feature_image)
    VALUES (@NewID, ffeature_name, ppattern_utqg, ffeature_descrip, ffeature_image);
END IF;

END
```

Comment: What do you mean "unable to create", what more precisely is your issue? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. The function you are looking for is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id
```

will return

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```